# Assign application to user based on e-mail address

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In our school we use the Azure AD. Currently we have two custom applications `A` and `B`.

We should assign application `A` to all the users with mail address `*@student.example.com` and the users with `@example.com` to application `B`.

How can we assign the users based on this criteria without doing in manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Graph API to automate this process. Here is a PowerShell Script I wrote to use the Graph API.

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll'

# Some common fields to log into your tenant.
$tenantID = "<your tenantID>"
$loginEndpoint = "https://login.windows.net/"

# The default redirect URI and client id.
# No need to change them.
$redirectURI = New-Object System.Uri ("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob")
$clientID = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"

$username = "<a global user of your tenant>"

$email_prefix1 = "*@student.example.com"
$email_prefix2 = "*@example.com"

# The display name of your AD apps, It's better if one does not contain another,
# because I am using the filter "startwith".
$apps1 = "<the display name of you first AD application>"
$apps2 = "<the display name of you second AD application>"

$resource = "https://graph.windows.net/"

# logging into your tenant to get the authorization header.
$authString = $loginEndpoint + $tenantID

$authenticationContext = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext ($authString, $false)

$promptBehaviour = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior]::Auto

$userIdentifierType = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifierType]::RequiredDisplayableId

$userIdentifier = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifier ($username, $userIdentifierType)

$authenticationResult = $authenticationContext.AcquireToken($resource, $clientID, $redirectURI, $promptBehaviour, $userIdentifier); 

# construct authorization header for the REST API.
$authHeader = $authenticationResult.AccessTokenType + " " + $authenticationResult.AccessToken
$headers = @{"Authorization"=$authHeader; "Content-Type"="application/json"}

# getting the service principal object id of the 2 AD apps.
$uri = "https://graph.windows.net/$tenantID/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.5&`$filter=startswith(displayName,'$apps1')"

$apps = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers $headers

$app1_objectId = $apps.value[0].objectId

$uri = "https://graph.windows.net/$tenantID/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.5&`$filter=startswith(displayName,'$apps2')"

$apps = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers $headers

$app2_objectId = $apps.value[0].objectId

# getting the users in the tenant.
$uri = "https://graph.windows.net/$tenantID/users?api-version=1.5"

$users = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers $headers

# loop through the whole user list to assign the AD apps.
foreach ($user in $users.value){
    $userID = $user.objectId

    if ($user.otherMails[0] -like $email_prefix1){
        $resourceId = $app1_objectId
    }
    elseif ($user.otherMails[0] -like $email_prefix2){
        $resourceId = $app2_objectId
    }
    else{
        continue
    }

    # Leave the id to be 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.
    # This is exactly how Azure Classic Portal handles user assigning.
    # That means if you assign a user to an AD application in the portal,
    # the appRoleAssignment will have the id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.
    $body = @"
{"id":  "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
 "principalId":  "$userID",
 "resourceId":  "$resourceId"
}
"@


    $uri = "https://graph.windows.net/$tenantID/users/$userID/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.5"
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body
}
```

Notice that I am using the email address in otherMails. If you are using Live id, that email address is just the user's live id. If you are using organization id, you can have it set in the classic portal as field Alternate email address.

[image]

Comment: Two little questions: I suppose I need to change the `$clientID`? Where can I find it? Do I need to create it in the Azure portal? Is the `$id` within the `$body` the same id?

Sorry for these questions, but we are completely new to Azure.

Comment: The `&clientID` I use here is the default client id, you don't need to create it. It's hardcoded in Azure. And, about the id in `$body`, you should leave it like that. If you are familiar with RBAC in Azure, you would know that there are different roles for service principal, such as Owner, Reader, and Contributor. That id should represent one of these. But, this is just assigning user to an AD application. We are not using RBAC at all, so `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` is good enough. And, that is exactly how Azure Classic Portal handles user assigning.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!